# error compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'

Tags: android, android-studio

Este es mi build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.oscar.myrecyclerview"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

me marca error en 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0' y estoy usando en todos los sitios su version y no se porque me marca este error agradezco sus respuestas de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que tengo en el android estudio y no se porque me da el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay esta que antes no salia bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si colocas el puntero del mouse sobre el "error" podrás observar un mensaje similar a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En realidad no es un error es un aviso** el cual indica:

> ### GradleCompatible
>
> Summary: Incompatible Gradle Versions
>
> Priority: 8 / 10 Severity: Error Category: Correctness
>
> [Hay algunas combinaciones de bibliotecas, o herramientas y
>   bibliotecas, que son Incompatibles, o puede conducir a errores. Una de
>   estas incompatibilidades está compilar una versión de las bibliotecas de
>   soporte de Android que no es la versión más reciente (o En particular,
>   una versión inferior a su targetSdkVersion.)](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks)

Lo cierto es que en tu `build.gradle` se debe tratar de definir una versión similar a la definida en  `targetSdkVersion`.